# 301 htaccess redirects with two separate URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two URLs pointing to the same directory, let's call them www.english.com and www.french.com. My htaccess file has a redirect as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /one http://www.english.com/#/one
```

If someone goes to www.english/one they are taken to the revised URL above, but the french URL also redirects to the English. Is there a way to have an if statement of kinds to direct www.french.com/one to www.french.com/#/one while keeping the English redirect in order?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with `Redirect`. But it is possible using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^one$ /#/one [R,L,NE]
```

Comment: Awesome that works. For anyone else interested, it also works with 301 redirects if you simply take out the hard coded URL. I was under the assumption it was necessary, but the following is valid:

Redirect 301 /one /#/one

Comment: You could do a 301 by using `[R=301,L,NE]`